# DevStack: failed to create new CentOS instance

Tags: openstack, devstack

After deployed DevStack, I managed to create cirros instances. Now I want create CentOS instance:

1. I download image `CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1608.qcow2` from [here].(http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/)
2. Then I run `nova boot --flavor 75c84ea2-d5b0-4d99-b935-08f654122aa3 --image 997f51bd-1ee2-4cdb-baea-6cef766bf191 --security-groups 207880e9-165f-4295-adfd-1f91ac96aaaa --nic net-id=26c05c99-b82d-403f-a988-fc07d3972b6b centos-1`
3. Then I run `nova list`, it gives: `b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee | centos-1 | ERROR  | -          | NOSTATE`
4. It is in `ERROR` state, so I grep log with that `b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee` (instance id): `grep b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee *.log`
5. The grep returns:

Result:

> n-api.log:2016-10-13 22:09:27.975 DEBUG nova.compute.api
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] block_device_mapping
>   [BlockDeviceMapping(boot_index=0,connection_info=None,created_at=,delete_on_termination=True,deleted=,deleted_at=,destination_type='local',device_name=None,device_type='disk',disk_bus=None,guest_format=None,id=,image_id='997f51bd-1ee2-4cdb-baea-6cef766bf191',instance=,instance_uuid=,no_device=False,snapshot_id=None,source_type='image',tag=None,updated_at=,volume_id=None,volume_size=None),
>   BlockDeviceMapping(boot_index=-1,connection_info=None,created_at=,delete_on_termination=True,deleted=,deleted_at=,destination_type='local',device_name=None,device_type='disk',disk_bus=None,guest_format=None,id=,image_id=None,instance=,instance_uuid=,no_device=False,snapshot_id=None,source_type='blank',tag=None,updated_at=,volume_id=None,volume_size=1)]
>   from (pid=12331) _bdm_validate_set_size_and_instance
>   /opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/api.py:1239 n-api.log:2016-10-13
>   22:09:28.117 DEBUG nova.compute.api
>   [req-d9327bbd-d333-4d37-8651-57e95d21396b admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] Fetching instance by UUID from
>   (pid=12331) get /opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/api.py:2215
>   n-api.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.184 DEBUG neutronclient.v2_0.client
>   [req-d9327bbd-d333-4d37-8651-57e95d21396b admin admin] GET call to
>   neutron for
>   http://10.61.148.89:9696/v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee
>   used request id req-2b427b03-67d9-474e-be93-b631b6a2ba78 from
>   (pid=12331) _append_request_id
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py:127
>   n-api.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.195 INFO nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server
>   [req-d9327bbd-d333-4d37-8651-57e95d21396b admin admin] 10.61.148.89
>   "GET /v2.1/servers/b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee HTTP/1.1"
>   status: 200 len: 2018 time: 0.0843861 n-api.log:2016-10-13
>   22:09:52.232 DEBUG neutronclient.v2_0.client
>   [req-415982d6-9ff4-4c80-99a8-46e1765a58d9 admin admin] GET call to
>   neutron for
>   http://10.61.148.89:9696/v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee&device_id=d6c67c2f-0d21-4ef8-bcfe-eba852ed0cc1 used request id req-645a777a-35df-456e-a982-433e97cdb0e7 from
>   (pid=12331) _append_request_id
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py:127
>   n-api.log:2016-10-13 22:17:04.476 DEBUG neutronclient.v2_0.client
>   [req-3b1c4dff-d9e9-41a5-9719-5bbb7c68085c admin admin] GET call to
>   neutron for
>   http://10.61.148.89:9696/v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee&device_id=d6c67c2f-0d21-4ef8-bcfe-eba852ed0cc1 used request id req-eb8bd6ef-1ecb-4c41-9355-26e4edb84d5c from
>   (pid=12330) _append_request_id
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py:127
>   n-cond.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.170 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] Setting instance to ERROR state.
>   n-cond.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.304 DEBUG nova.network.neutronv2.api
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] deallocate_for_instance() from
>   (pid=19162) deallocate_for_instance
>   /opt/stack/nova/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py:1154
>   n-cond.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.350 DEBUG neutronclient.v2_0.client
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] GET call to
>   neutron for
>   http://10.61.148.89:9696/v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee
>   used request id req-9dc53ce3-1f4e-4619-a22e-ce98a6f1c382 from
>   (pid=19162) _append_request_id
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py:127
>   n-cond.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.351 DEBUG nova.network.neutronv2.api
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] Instance cache missing network
>   info. from (pid=19162) _get_preexisting_port_ids
>   /opt/stack/nova/nova/network/neutronv2/api.py:2133
>   n-cond.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.362 DEBUG nova.network.base_api
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] [instance:
>   b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee] Updating instance_info_cache
>   with network_info: [] from (pid=19162)
>   update_instance_cache_with_nw_info
>   /opt/stack/nova/nova/network/base_api.py:43 grep: n-dhcp.log: No such
>   file or directory n-sch.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.166 DEBUG nova.filters
>   [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin admin] Filtering
>   removed all hosts for the request with instance ID
>   'b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee'. Filter results:
>   [('RetryFilter', [(u'i-z78fw9mn', u'i-z78fw9mn')]),
>   ('AvailabilityZoneFilter', [(u'i-z78fw9mn', u'i-z78fw9mn')]),
>   ('RamFilter', [(u'i-z78fw9mn', u'i-z78fw9mn')]), ('DiskFilter', None)]
>   from (pid=19243) get_filtered_objects
>   /opt/stack/nova/nova/filters.py:129 n-sch.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.166
>   INFO nova.filters [req-6b5bf92a-ce53-46d4-8965-b54e02d21aef admin
>   admin] Filtering removed all hosts for the request with instance ID
>   'b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee'. Filter results: ['RetryFilter:
>   (start: 1, end: 1)', 'AvailabilityZoneFilter: (start: 1, end: 1)',
>   'RamFilter: (start: 1, end: 1)', 'DiskFilter: (start: 1, end: 0)']
>   q-svc.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.184 INFO neutron.wsgi
>   [req-2b427b03-67d9-474e-be93-b631b6a2ba78 admin
>   55a846ac28f847eca8521ff71dea8633] 10.61.148.89 - - [13/Oct/2016
>   22:09:28] "GET
>   /v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 211 0.038510 q-svc.log:2016-10-13 22:09:28.350 INFO
>   neutron.wsgi [req-9dc53ce3-1f4e-4619-a22e-ce98a6f1c382 admin
>   55a846ac28f847eca8521ff71dea8633] 10.61.148.89 - - [13/Oct/2016
>   22:09:28] "GET
>   /v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 211 0.042906 q-svc.log:2016-10-13 22:09:52.233 INFO
>   neutron.wsgi [req-645a777a-35df-456e-a982-433e97cdb0e7 admin
>   55a846ac28f847eca8521ff71dea8633] 10.61.148.89 - - [13/Oct/2016
>   22:09:52] "GET
>   /v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee&device_id=d6c67c2f-0d21-4ef8-bcfe-eba852ed0cc1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1241 0.041629 q-svc.log:2016-10-13 22:17:04.477 INFO
>   neutron.wsgi [req-eb8bd6ef-1ecb-4c41-9355-26e4edb84d5c admin
>   55a846ac28f847eca8521ff71dea8633] 10.61.148.89 - - [13/Oct/2016
>   22:17:04] "GET
>   /v2.0/ports.json?device_id=b9f97618-085b-4d2b-bc94-34f3b953e2ee&device_id=d6c67c2f-0d21-4ef8-bcfe-eba852ed0cc1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1241 0.044646

Now I have no idea about what's going wrong about that instance deployment, could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: can you share the outputs of following:     neutron net-list, nova flavor-list

Comment: @abhilash_goyal Thanks, I solved this with some work arounds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions in order to discard common problems:

- The flavor: The flavor you are using is the same you used with cirros ?. Is the answer is yes: That flavor include a specific disk size for the root disk ?. If "yes", check the minimum disk size required for the centos generic image you are using. Either the image need a bigger disk, or, the disk is to big for your box. Then, check your available HD space, the flavor specs, and the image specs.
- Network: Let's discard neutron. Instead of assigning the network, assign a port. Create a port in neutron, and in the nova boot command, assign the port to the vm instead of assigning the network (--nic port-id=port-uuid).
- Glance image definition: When you created the glance image from the downloaded qcow2 file, did you included any metadata item that is forcing the image to request a cinder-based disk ?. Did you included any metadata at all ?. If so, get rid of all metadata items on the glance image.
- Try again to launch a cirros instance. If the cirros goes OK, then it's something with the image (maybe any of the above: glance, flavor, disk space).

Let me know what you find !.